# On the sum $\sum_{k\le n}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-hypothesis

I was looking for information about the Riemann Hypothesis, and I found that the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to the statement $$\sum_{k\le n}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}=O(n^{-1/2+\varepsilon})$$

If we consider the sum $S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}$ and we expand it, we have that $$S=1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{13}+...$$

Where the denominators are all the square free integers.

I noticed that if we set $$\frac{1}{2}S=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{20}-\frac{1}{22}-\frac{1}{26}+...$$

And we subtract, most of the terms vanish and we get that $$\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)S=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{28}+\frac{1}{44}+...$$

$$\frac{1}{2}S=\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{11}+...\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{2}S=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{11}+...\right)$$

And finally, $$S=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{11}+...\right)$$

Therefore, it seems we can establish that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p}\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$$

As partial sums of $\sum_{p}\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$ are well known by Mertens' second theorem, my question is: is my reasoning valid? could it help or give some additional information to get the desired statement $\sum_{k\le n}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}=O(n^{-1/2+\varepsilon})$?

Comment: If the last equality were correct, $S$ would diverge.

Comment: Before we rearrange the terms in $S$, we need to establish that it is absolutely convergent. See the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)

Comment: Thanks! I thought the result was a little bit weird... with the Riemann rearrangement theorem now I see why!

Comment: Which would be (if any) the interpretation of the result obtained?

Comment: the Riemann rearrangement theorem shows that you can rearrange a conditionally (but not absolutely) convergent series to do anything you want (converge to whatever value you wish, have as many limit points as you wish, etc) so I would guess the above means nothing as you can take any conditional series and rearrange it so the partial sums are very close to the partial sums of the reciprocal of the primes series etc

Comment: Thanks @Conrad! I have realized what you comment after reading @K.defaoite wikipedia link... so the question is closed ;)